# How to open a toggle feature by clicking on another link

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, toggle

I am trying to make a feature that scrolls down to a toggle function and opens up automatically when it scrolls down.

```
<a href="#!" id="linkbro">click me </a>
<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit,
 sed diam nonummy nibh euismod tincidunt ut laoreet dolore
 magna aliquam erat volutpat. Ut wisi enim ad minim veniam,
 quis nostrud exerci tation ullamcorper suscipit lobortis nisl
 ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis autem vel eum iriure
 dolor in hendrerit in vulputate velit esse molestie consequat,
 vel illum dolore eu feugiat nulla facilisis at vero eros et
 accumsan et iusto odio dignissim qui blandit praesent luptatum
 zzril delenit augue duis dolore te feugait nulla facilisi.
 Nam liber tempor cum soluta nobis eleifend option congue
 nihil imperdiet doming id quod mazim placerat facer possim
 assum. Typi non habent claritatem insitam; est usus legentis
 in iis qui facit eorum claritatem. Investigationes
 demonstraverunt lectores legere me lius quod ii legunt saepius.
 Claritas est etiam processus dynamicus, qui sequitur mutationem
 consuetudium lectorum. Mirum est notare quam littera gothica,
 quam nunc putamus parum claram, anteposuerit litterarum formas
 humanitatis per seacula quarta decima et quinta decima. Eodem
 modo typi, qui nunc nobis videntur parum clari, fiant sollemnes
 in futurum.</p>
<div id="fine">
    <button class="show_hide">Toggle</button>
    <p class="content">
     This is the paragraph to end all paragraphs.  You
     should feel <em>lucky</em> to have seen such a paragraph in
     your life.  Congratulations!
    </p>
</div>
```

My JavaScript. The scroll down function works but the toggle does not open up.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $(".content").hide();
    $("#linkbro").click(function() {
        $('html, body').animate({
            scrollTop: $("#fine").offset().top - 50
        }, 2000);
        $(this).next('.content').slideToggle(200);
    });
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You an use *$(this).siblings*.  Change:
**$(this).next('.content').slideToggle(200);**
To:
**$(this).siblings('div').find('.content').slideToggle(200);**

And perhaps you wanted your Toggle button to be this?

```
$('.show_hide').click(function(){
    $(this).next('.content').slideToggle(200);
});
```

Here's your updated script:

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(".content").hide();

    $("#linkbro").click(function() {
        $('html, body').animate({
            scrollTop: $("#fine").offset().top - 50
        }, 2000);
        $(this).siblings('div').find('.content').slideToggle(200);
    });

    $('.show_hide').click(function(){
        $(this).next('.content').slideToggle(200);
    });
});
</script>
```